# what is the difference between Swarm and BigchainDB?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, storage, swarm, database

Are both Swarm and BigchainDB complementary to ethereum or do they function independently? What are their applications?

Answer (score 2):

Both Swarm and BigchanDB are complementary to the Ethereum platform.

You can use both of them in your Ethereum contracts to either host and distribute content (Swarm) or use a database system (BigchainDB). These are things you don't have in Ethereum.

Comment: you can not access either swarm or bigchaindb from within a solidity smart-contract